# 'pvk2pfx.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command in command promt

Tags: azure, cmd, azure-cloud-services

for creating certificate run this command

pvk2pfx.exe -pvk C:\myCerts\ELServer.pvk -spc C:\myCerts\ELServer.cer -pfx C:\myCerts\ELServer.pfx

following error occurred in command prompt

'pvk2pfx.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 5):

I got exactly this error. The first thing I did was try to search for the .exe using Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter pvk2pfx.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

I could not find it but I could find `makecert.exe` with this command.

Turned out I did not have the package `Desktop development with C++` installed for Visual Studio 2017. After I added this everything worked. Remember to run the command through `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017`.

If you do not use Visual Studio 2017 you can download `Windows Driver Kit (WDK)` from here instead:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran the command in VS2012 command prompt which is available in

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\Visual Studio Tools\` in the name of

```
VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt
```

You can also use VS2017 command prompt which is available in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\VC` in the name of

```
x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017
```

You can do windows + s key and then type command and open the X86 based command prompt to run the command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's not in your PATH environment variable. add it to PATH or just navigate to the directory where that exe is.